# Pausar animação com o setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, react-native, animação

Estou usando a biblioteca Lottie no React native e quero animar um objeto e depois de 2.5 segundos pausar a animação, mas o settTimeOut me retorna um erro. O comando `anim.pause()` funciona corretamente fora do setTimeOut.

Declaração da animação:

```
<LottieView
    ref={(animation) => {
       anim = animation;}}
    style={{width: wh * 10, height: wh * 10}}
    source={send}
/>
```

Pegando a referência do componente Lottie:

```
let anim = useRef(null);
```

Onde chamo a função:

```
function Send(){
  anim.play();
  setTimeout(() => { anim.pause() }, 2500);
}
```

O erro: TypeError: null is not object (evaluating 'anim.pause')

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho melhor você usar:

```
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    
  clearInterval(interval);

  }, 1000);
```

clearInterval para o setInterval.